# Help with Electric Panel

Tags: electrical-panel

Ok this panel is on the outside of a small cottage. The electric for the house turns off when you turn off the 100 amp double breaker on the right.  My question is should this control another panel or breaker box inside the house. [image] DO not understand why they would have a 100amp double breaker for the house only... Help????

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What do the other breakers control? And, would you feel safe about taking the cover off the breaker box and getting a couple of pictures of the inside?

Comment: The other lower breakers control the dryer, AC, Outside RV outlet. The 100 Amp send power to the house only... Thanks for the response

Comment: The short answer is yes, that double pull 100 amp breakers turns of another panel, likely inside.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like that panel in the picture is the panel for all outside stuff, high voltage appliances, and other high demand applications. That 100 Amp double pole is for the inside panel.

Answer (score 1):

This setup is quite normal. The 125 is your main disconnect it turns everything off. The 100 amp feeds your main panel in the house but even though it is the main it is considered a sub panel and the neutrals should be isolated from the grounds by current code standards.